# Using Modal View Controller with UITabBarController and UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My application is embedded within a `UITabBarController` and has 4 tabs. 3 of the 4 tabs are embedded within `UINavigationControllers` and the other is not.

I have found if the `ViewController` has a `NavigationBar` and the I am using `present view controller modally` when segueing, and the presenting controller has `define context`selected the modal view appears underneath both the `NavigationBar` and `UITabBar`. If `define context`is not selected then the modal view is displayed above the `UINavigationBar` but still underneath the `UITabBar`. Like So,

[image]

The problem here is that because the `Modal View Controller` is presented underneath the `UITabBar` the user can still access the `UITabBar` and change tabs before dismissing which results in a black screen.

However if the `presenting view controller` has not got a `UINavigationBar` and has not got `define context` selected then the `modal view controller` will take up the whole view and is displayed above the `UITabBar`. This means the user cannot switch tabs before dismissing the modal view. Which is the intended effect I am after, however how can I achieve this when using a `UINavigationBar` so the user cannot switch tabs  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've created your segue in a storyboard, select the segue to the modal you want to be presented over everything, and set the `Presentation` attribute to `Over Full Screen`:

[image: Attributes of a segue]

If you're presenting the modal programmatically, assuming you named your view to present `yourModal` set the `modalPresentationStyle` as such:

```
yourModal.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
```